# Java: custom cursor for Jscrollpane or Jsplitpane?

Tags: java, swing, cursor, jscrollpane, jsplitpane

any way to set custom cursor from image for a jscrollpane in a jsplitpane panel?

right now I get a custom icon that displays in the entire Jframe and I would like it limited to a specific jscrollpane.

anyway to make it display on top of heavyweight component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agreed, I saw and I have some issues with `setCursor` to the `JScrollPane`, this method must be called on EDT, [(on EDT) in most of cases works for me correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6060678/714968)

I'd suggest use default `Cursors` returned from `Native OS`, or use `JWindow` for creating `Custom Cursor` or [????](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5957405/714968)