# Tooltip below caret position in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jtextarea, caret

I'm trying to display a tooltip below caret position, the same way Eclipse prompts "Enter new name, press **Enter** to refactor" when renaming local variable. I assume that I can't use ToolTip as they are binded to mouse and not caret, so I'd have to adapt `ToolTipManager.showTipWindow()` code for my purposes. Here, the only problem is calculating caret position in pixels. I attempted:

```
Caret c = editor.getCaret();
Point location = c.getMagicCaretPosition();
```

where subsequent use of `location` causes NPE. I guess this happens when caret is not visible, so the method is unreliable. Is there a way to convert character offset in the TextArea, to the Point location?

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5957241/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `modelToView()` method of `JTextArea`.