# JLabel's position changes to weird location when resizing the frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I'm just doing my personal project that draws a basic map using Swing.

I have many issues but the worst one is that the position of `JLable`s changes every time I

1. Resize the frame
2. Set them invisible and visible again (setvisible(false)->setvisible(true))
3. Move the screen to another tab 'Map 2' and come back to Map 1 (The frame has `JTabbedPane`)

It's sad that I don't have enough reputation to upload images :(

all the `JLable`s are located on the top of the `JPanel`.

It's like

Before
.-----------------------------------------------
.-----------------------------------------------
.---------Label1-----------------------------
.-----------------------------------------------
.------------------Label2--------------------
.-----------------------------------------------
.-------------------------------Label3-------
.-----------------------------------------------
.-----------------------------------------------
.-----------------------------------------------

After
.-----------------------------------------------
.---------Label1 Label2 Label3-----------
.-----------------------------------------------
.-----------------------------------------------
.-----------------------------------------------
.-----------------------------------------------
.-----------------------------------------------
.-----------------------------------------------
.-----------------------------------------------
.-----------------------------------------------

I also tried using `setLocation(new Point(x,y));` after resizing happens but nothing came out.

Any tips will be appreciated. :)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Post your source, please

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Thanks David I'll keep the post in mind for future questions and this one! But the panel that contains those Labels does not use LayoutManager. So the Labels are located using 'setLocation'. So setLocation for the first time works but not for later :(

Comment: +1 for ACSII art; an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) is always welcome, and a [picture](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) is worth _n_ words. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have used [absolute positioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) without setting the layout accordingly. Refreshing the display in the presence of `FlowLayout`, the default for `JPanel`, causes the layout you see in *after*. Using `setLayout(null)` may work, but the preferred approach is to use the intended [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: I edited Images for other viewers. And the reason why I didn't use layout manager is to locate Labels anywhere on the panel.

Comment: Good use case for absolute positioning; also consider [tooltips](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5957412/230513).