# How to implement a mouse listener that returns the char the mouse is pointing at in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, mouselistener

I have a JTable with a mouse listener attached. I need to get the char that has been clicked in a table cell. I can get the row and column numbers, but I can't get the `Element` (which I think has to be char in a table cell) that the mouse is pointing to. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

- [JTable.rowAtPoint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#rowAtPoint%28java.awt.Point%29) and [JTable.columnAtPoint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#columnAtPoint%28java.awt.Point%29) returns coordinated for [getValueAt(int row, int column)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29) from unknow `mouseevent` (not sure if is there [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) or [MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html))
- more efficient will be add [ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to the [JTable (SINGLE_SELECTION_Model)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection), because listening for event came from keyboard too
- I hope that your question isn't about [Specifying Tool Tips for Cells](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#celltooltip)

Comment: I know how to get the row and column numbers the mouse points at. What I need is to get the `Element` (char) within the cell that the mouse points at.

Comment: don't know direct way Renderer v.s. Char, [do you mean something like as, see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5957405/714968)

Comment: Yes, something like that, but fora JTable instead. I can show you how I get the `Element` in the table editor, but I can't use it for the Table itself when it's not in editing mode.

Comment: there must be way to get (convert relative mouse coordinates) have look at, search for SwingUtilities.convertXxx, getDeepestComponentAt, convertPointXxx, layoutCompoundLabel in the answers by (@camickr, @StanislavL and @trashgod), sorry no idea, never needed that

Comment: ...and I need to override the `mouseMoved()` and `mouseClicked()` methods instead.

Comment: above mentioned methods are for MouseEvents and Cursor, doesn't matter if came from Mouse/MouseMotionListener

Comment: [custom RolloverSupport by @aephyr](http://aephyr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/), even code example is about JList, there no issue to change to the JTable