# Duration of tooltip displaying in Java

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, duration

Is it possible to change display duration of SPECIFIC tooltip?
I know in Java there is ToolTipManager, but any operations on this manager have impact on all tooltips.

Comment: Is it possible to change display duration of SPECIFIC tooltip? -- not, does not match the efforts you made (even you can be able to override protected methods in API), easier will be to create JWindow with parent (important)

Comment: You can try to add a listener and set desired value in the ToolTipManager on IN event and restore the value on OUT event.

Comment: mKorbel, do you mean i should use JWindow and show it always when mouse is over some JComponent (using for example some counter in thread which make a countdown)?

Comment: there are two ways 1. (very complicated) by using PropertyChangeListener and AncesorListener with Swing Timer (mentioned by @StanislavL ???) 2. create JWindow (I'm see here [layout JLabel a few times instead of JWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5957405/714968)) and playing with setVisible(true/false) and Swing Timer, EDIT and Point for location rellative to parent