# Show tooltip on word - after searching text file for meaning

Tags: java, swing, jframe, tooltip

I want create a JFrame in java with some Text in that.
In my text, some of words need to be explained, so I want to do this:
For example if my text is: "Obama is president in USA", I want if the cursor is on "Obama" a tool-tip open and explain about Obama, the meaning of words are stored in a file and I can search it for.

I want (if it is possible) the cursor change to hand and the the tool-tip appear, also if user click on that, full meaning of that word appear in `JTextArea` or something like that.

In the end, I want if words in my text has meaning in my file, the color of word change to blue.

Comment: please whats wrong with  [question asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[java]%20[swing]%20tooltip) and description in official Oracle tutorial  [How to use Tooltips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) voting to close

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text-mouseover popups over a Swing JTextArea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957241/text-mouseover-popups-over-a-swing-jtextarea)

Comment: You have our permission to 'Go for it!'.  Since you failed to ask a question, I'm voting to close as 'too broad'.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create custom TextArea and override the `getToolTipText(MouseEvent)` method

```
public class CustomToolTipArea extends JTextArea {
  public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
    int pos = viewToModel(event.getPoint());
    // calculate vord at Position in text and determine the tooltip text for the word.
  }
}
```