# mouseEntered does not work as hover over

Tags: java, swing

I am relatively new to the Java Swing library and I am attempting to write a program that detects a mouse hover event and shows a popup. I am using the mouseEntered event, however it is only being triggered when the mouse enters from outside the entire frame, as opposed to hovering over different components within the frame. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Are you adding your mouse event listener object to the entire frame? I think you should be able to add it to your component within the frame, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957241/text-mouseover-popups-over-a-swing-jtextarea

Comment: Just use the [tool tips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) as that's exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse over triggers when the mouse pointer enters to a controller from another location. I think you will get the thing done with **MouseMoved** event of the controller.